# Duplication Error on Twitter Bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, npm

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

I have been cooking up a twitter bot that will retweet web development related content as a small side project following this tutorial at Rising Stack. [LINK](https://community.risingstack.com/node-js-twitter-bot-tutorial/)

Here is my code, I'm using node.js to create this and an NPM called 'TWIT'.

```
console.log('The follow/retweet bot is starting');

//Import statement fromt TWIT NPM  && CONFIG with secret keys. 
var Twit = require('twit'); 

var config = require('./config');

//Secret codes to connect to Twitter
var T = new Twit(config); 

//RETWEET BOT ======================

//find the latest tweet according the query 'q' in params
var retweet = function retweetIt() {
    var params = {
        q: '#coding, #webdev, #webdevelopment, #nodejs' , //required
        result_type: 'recent', 
        lang: 'en'
    }
    // for more parameters, see https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets
    T.get('search/tweets', params, function retweetIt(err, data) {
        // if there no errors
        if (!err) {
          // grab ID of tweet to retweet
            var retweetId = data.statuses[0].id_str;
            // Tell TWITTER to retweet
            T.post('statuses/retweet/:id', {
                id: retweetId
            }, function(err, response) {
                if (response) {
                    console.log('Retweeted!!!');
                }
                // if there was an error while tweeting
                if (err) {
                    console.log('Something went wrong while RETWEETING... Duplication maybe...');
                }
            });
        }
        // if unable to Search a tweet
        else {
          console.log('Something went wrong while SEARCHING...');
        }
    });
}

retweet(); 

//retweet every 5 minutes
setInterval(retweet, 1000*60*5);
```

When I run this in my terminal, the first thing I see is "The follow/retweet bot is starting!" Which is great, I know its starting.

Following after that the variable retweet runs the functions that make retweeting happen. However, when I do I get this: [image]

I get BOTH the (err) and (response). I don't know much about duplications in code, but is it the function running multiple times and making an error message? I have had success with this particular build before, I have been able to post messages and retweet. Ideally I would like to retweet every 30 minutes or an hour.

Can someone explain 'duplication' and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Typically, a node.js API returns either `err` or `response`, **not both**. Can you add `if (err) console.log(err)` so we can see the error message?